# Cannot get Date to an arraylis from DB

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

I wrote a small Javafx ToDo app to list my Tasks with a deadline date (duedate) from Type Date in a Derby DB.

What I'm trying to do is to get the Date record (duedate) from DB into an Arraylist and change the Background of the Label which shows the duedate.

When I run the sql statement in the DB I get the correct record! but I cannot get them in the Arraylist. **printLn shows nothing and I don't get any Error.**

if I get correct records I would see a change in the Background of the Label and / or I would get the records in the System.out.println.

here is my method:

```
public ArrayList<Task> getDelayedTasks() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    conn = DBConnUtil.getConnection();

    String s = "select duedate from tasks where duedate <= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE);";
     ps = conn.prepareStatement(s);
     rs = ps.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<Task> delayedTaskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Task task;
        task = new Task(rs.getDate("duedate"));
        delayedTaskList.add(task);

        dueDateLabel.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);

         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(delayedTaskList.toArray()));
         System.out.println(task);
    }
    return delayedTaskList;      
}
```

and here how I call it in the Controller:

```
void initialize() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        getDelayedTasks();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CellController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

and here is the Task Class:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Task {

    private int taskId;
    private String task;
    private String description;
    private Timestamp dateCreated;
    private Date duedate;



    public Task() {
    }

    public Task(Timestamp datecreated, String description, String task, Date duedate) {
        this.dateCreated = datecreated;
        this.description = description;
        this.task = task;
        this.duedate = duedate;
    }

    Task(Date duedate) {
        this.duedate = duedate;
    }

    public Timestamp getDatecreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDatecreated(Timestamp datecreated) {
        this.dateCreated = datecreated;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public int getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskId(int taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    public Date getDueDate() {
        return duedate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(Date duedate) {
        this.duedate = duedate;
    }

}
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? 
Thank you

after the advices from Mr. @RealSkeptic I found out that the method is never called! Now when I call it from somewhere else, I get a list of records like this:

```
10.12.2019 00:00:00
18.12.2019 00:00:00
```

I think what I need now is a loop or something to change the Label Background.

78

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I'm not getting any error and not getting any result. the app runs but as you can see in the code, I get nothing into the ArrayList and the Label Background stays the same!

Comment: Your method throws `SQLException`. Who catches that exception if it's thrown? How do you know that you got the correct record? What's a `Task`?

Comment: as far as I understand your question, I changed the code like this:

void initialize() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            getDelayedTasks();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CellController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

but there is no change in the result. the App runs, no Errors! if I get correct records I would see a change in the Background of the Label and / or I would get the records in the System.out.println.

Comment: Task is an Object (Class) which contains the DB fields and constructors.

Comment: Ok Sorry, this is my first Question here :)

Comment: OK. Now your question is clearer. It's still something that can't be answered, though, because we don't know what's in the database, if you are connecting to the correct database, and if the `initialize()` method gets called at all. A debugger will tell you all of that.

Comment: Sir, you are absolutely wright! the initialize() is never called! (I always thought it is the first thing called in FXML Controller!).
I called it from somewhere else and now I am getting a List of records like this :
mytasks.Task@2397b05
mytasks.Task@64a843f
mytasks.Task@37592e27

Comment: just to answer the DB question, the DB is correct and the duedate column is of type Date. and I'am getting the records in the fxml Label correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's because you didn't override the `toString()` method in `Task`.

Comment: _but the Background of the Label stays the same_ Changes to the GUI, like changing the background of a `Label` needs to happen in the JavaFX Application Thread. Is that the case?

Comment: @Abra the Background of the Label should change depending on the result in the List!